# Transferring form input to another page through variable in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to send an input from a form in one page to a form on another page through variable but it is not working for me.
This is the form for the first page:

```html
   <form method="POST" action="{{ route('invite') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="username" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Username') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="username" type="username" class="form-control @error('username') is-invalid @enderror" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}" >

                                @error('username')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

        

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Invite') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

and the controller for the first page:

```html
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
class InviteController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers;
    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::REGISTER;
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     *  @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
    public function bids(Request $request){
        $request->session()->put('username', $request->username);
        return redirect()->route('register');

    }
    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        ]);
    }
    protected function create()
    {
    }
}
```

this is the form for the second page:

```html
 <?php $username=  Session::get('username') ; ?> 
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}"  autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="username" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Username') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="username" type="username" class="form-control @error('username') is-invalid @enderror" name="username" value=" <?php echo $username; ?>" readonly>

                                @error('username')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" >

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Register') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

and the controller for this 2nd page:

```html
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
include 'vendor/autoload.php';
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */
    use RegistersUsers;
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     *  @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
    public function bids(Request $request)
    {            $request->session()->get('username');
    }
    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'randString' => 'same:motto'
        ]);
    }
    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),

        ]);
    }
}
```

I've tried using the session method in this code, but it did not work. I tried the POST method but I do not know how to properly implement that.

Comment: SESDIONS Set and get,  use this way `Session::put('variableName', $value);` To get the variable `Session::get('variableName');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried redirecting with the username in the url?

For example

```
Redirect::to('form2?username_='. Session::get('username'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I use that like this way.

```
<input id="username" type="text" class="form-control @error('username') is-invalid @enderror" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}" >
```

Add this top of your code

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
```

And in your method add like this

```
Session::put('username',$request->username);
```

And your blade use like this

```
{{Session::get('username')}}
```

Comment: still shows blank on the username, is it cause the form on second page also uses the name "username" ?

Comment: first in your controller `dd($request->username)` then again use `dd(Session::get('username'))` then it is clear to you. I am sure your `dd($request->username)` is empty.

Comment: yes its returning null, is this cause both controllers start a new instance?

public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }```

Comment: I mean, it should return the username from the form, but its returning null, i dunno if the instance function were causing it, i tried removing it but it had no effect, still returns nulls, its not receiving the input from the previous form.